# Pandas: How to find line breaks in a DF?

Tags: python, pandas, azureml-python-sdk

I need to find all representations of **line breaks** to circumvent a problem created by AzureML's designers, which is as follows:

```
By default (support_multi_line=False), all line breaks,
including those in quoted field values,
will be interpreted as a record break.
```

Consequently, this design choice is breaking my DF by inflating its records and creating errors in my pipeline.

I have attempted this:

```
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["", ""], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

But it is not working -- line breaks are still being found in my DF -- what else should I be looking for?

Comment: Which column is it occuring in?

Answer (score 2):

[`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) searched for *whole values* in all rows and columns of the dataframe and replaces those values with the specified values. It doesn't replace parts of strings.

You're looking for [`df[column].str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```py
df[column] = df[column].str.replace('[\n|\r|\t]|\\\\[nrt]', '', regex=False)
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay -- just got around to testing. This strategy takes care of fewer line breaks than the above `[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"]` (i.e., the problem is slightly worse).

Comment: Oh really? I'm surprised to hear that. Will you please send a sample of your data in the question, particularly the rows that contain the bad data? I'd be able to help better if I could see what data you're actually dealing with